# how to purge nginx cache which vary by user agent

Tags: caching, nginx, fastcgi

a page has tow cache. one for pc web browser, another for mobile browser.

nginx can do this perfect.  follow is part of nginx conf content:

```
map $http_user_agent $device_type {
    default 'pc';
    ~(iPhone|Android|IEMobile|Balckberry) 'mobile';
}

#fast cgi cache def
fastcgi_cache_path  /data0/nginx-1.2.6/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=nginx_webpy_cache:30m inactive=1d;

fastcgi_temp_path /data0/nginx-1.2.6/cache/temp;
fastcgi_cache_key "$request_method$scheme$host$request_uri$device_type$is_args$args";
#end
```

as you see, i place $device_type into cache key for tow cache versions.

but i found with this conf, i can't purge nginx cache. how to purge these tow cache versions?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved this question.

follow is my solution.

first add map in nginx.conf's http scope:

```
map $http_user_agent $device_type {
    default 'pc';
    ~(iPhone|Android|IEMobile|Balckberry) 'mobile';
}
```

than you need edit fastcgi cache key, as follow:

```
  #fast cgi cache def
  fastcgi_cache_path  /data0/nginx-1.2.6/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=nginx_webpy_cache:30m inactive=1d;

  fastcgi_temp_path /data0/nginx-1.2.6/cache/temp;

  fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host/$device_type$request_uri$is_args$args";
  #end
```

I place variable $device_type into the cache key. now pc and mobile has different cache version.

notice: if you need purge cache, you should purge tow version.

if you are chinese, please see follow article:

[nginx cache with different user agent](http://outofmemory.cn/code-snippet/3357/nginx-cache-with-difference-user-agent)